# How to get url of all child,grand child pages using root path?

Tags: aem

I have a path of a root page and I want to retrieve all the child pages of root page and grandchild and grand grand child of root page. My structure is like this

```
rootPage
    |
    |
    |---------childPage
                    |
                    |
                    |---------grandChildPage
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |
                                    |----------------------grandGrandChildPages
```

So I want the path of all these pages. How can i get this?
currently i'm using this

```
adminSession = repository.loginAdministrative( repository.getDefaultWorkspace());
                   ResourceResolver resourceResolver = request.getResourceResolver();
                   PageManager pageManager = resourceResolver.adaptTo(PageManager.class);
                   List<String>pageList = new ArrayList();
                    Page rootPage = pageManager.getPage("/content/abc/roi");
                    Iterator<Page> rootPageIterator = rootPage.listChildren();
                    while(rootPageIterator.hasNext())
                    {
                    Page childPage =    rootPageIterator.next();
                    String path = childPage.getPath();
                    pageList.add(path);     
                    }
```

But it provides me the only the child pages of root page and if i use rootPage.hasChild() then i have to pass the string which i can't because i don't now the name of pages. Is there any method which returns boolean value whether a page has child pages or not. I just want list of all pages inside root page which include grandChild as well as grandgrandCHild of root page.

can anyone help ?

Comment: Which version of AEM are you using? From 5.6 onwards, you have the option to specify if you want to list all the descendant pages under a page.  Check the method `listChildren(PageFilter filter, boolean deep)` from the [Page API](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html)

Comment: in filter what i supposed to pass . like if my grandgrand child path is content/abc/def/ghi/jkl . and what in deep ?

Comment: i never used this FIlter interface before can you please explain

Comment: You can either pass a [PageFilter](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageFilter.html) or `null` for the filter and pass `true` for deep. Like this `listChildren(new PageFilter(), true)`

Comment: It is working fine for me. I guess the pages would have be marked as hideInNav, hence the filter might have rejected it. Else try `listChildren(null, true)`. This should work for you.

Comment: No its working fine now.. actually i didn't change the path... thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From AEM 5.6 onwards, you can use the [`listChildren(Filter<Page> filter, boolean deep)`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html#listChildren(com.day.cq.commons.Filter,%20boolean)) method available in `com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page` interface.

This would accept a [PageFilter](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/PageFilter.html) and a boolean value as arguments.

The PageFilter can be used, if you want to filter invalid and hidden pages. If you want all the pages to be listed pass `null` for this param.

For the boolean deep, if `false` it lists only the child pages, and if `true` would list all the descendants of the given page.

Hence, the code in the question can be modified either to

```
Iterator<Page> rootPageIterator = rootPage.listChildren(null, true);
```

or as

```
Iterator<Page> rootPageIterator = rootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter(), true);
```

Comment: can you please answer this one also ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570738/how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-basis-of-path-in-cq5