# How to create a directory on the basis of path in cq5?

Tags: aem, jcr

I have a String which is the path of the page for example `/content/xperia/public/events/eventeditor`. I am gererating the XML of this page and saving it to DAM, but I want to save it in the similar tree structure under `/content`.

I tried the following code

```
String page = "/content/xperia/public/events/eventeditor";
page = page.replace("/content", "/content/dam");
if (adminSession.nodeExists(page+ "/"+ "jcr:content")) {
    Node node = adminSession.getNode(page+ "/"+ "jcr:content");
    node.setProperty("jcr:data", sb.toString());                
} else {
    Node feedNode = JcrUtil.createPath(page,"nt:file", adminSession);           
    Node dataNode = JcrUtil.createPath(feedNode.getPath() + "/"+ "jcr:content", "nt:resource", adminSession);       
    dataNode.setProperty("jcr:data",sb.toString());
}
```

But it gives the following error

> No matching child node definition found for
>   {http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0}content

Because there is no such path in the repository. Is there a way through which I can create a directory on the fly. Because to save this file, I need to create  the entire tree `xperia/public/events` under `/content/dam` and then save `eventeditor.xml` in that directory .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code. The `JcrUtil.createPath(String absolutePath, String nodeType, Session session)` creates all the non-existent intermediate path with the given NodeType.

This means that all the nodes xperia, public and events are created with type `nt:file` instead of `sling:OrderedFolder`.

You can use the [`createPath(String absolutePath, boolean createUniqueLeaf, String intermediateNodeType, String nodeType, Session session, boolean autoSave)`](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createPath(java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20javax.jcr.Session,%20boolean)) method instead, to specify the type of intermediary nodes that are to be created.

```
String page = "/content/xperia/public/events/eventeditor";
page = page.replace("/content", "/content/dam");
page += ".xml";

if (adminSession.nodeExists(page+ "/"+ "jcr:content")) {
    Node node = adminSession.getNode(page+ "/"+ "jcr:content");
    node.setProperty("jcr:data", sb.toString());                
} else {
    Node feedNode = JcrUtil.createPath(page, true, "sling:OrderedFolder", "nt:file", adminSession, false);           
    Node dataNode = feedNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");       
    dataNode.setProperty("jcr:data",sb.toString());
}

adminSession.save();
```

Comment: Thanks Rakhi.... u r great.. it works :).. one more thing if i have to request these xml from third party application , forthat i need to pass the credentials in url. how can i pass so that i will get authenticate and get these xml data on request. suppose if my xml path is localhost:4504/xperian/roi/events.xml and cq password is admin  then what will be the url

Comment: I am not sure if it possible to send the credentials over URL. I think only basic authentication is possible that way. Anyways kindly post it as a separate question, so that others might be able to see it and reply as well.

Comment: ok i will ... i'm searching for that if still i dont find any solution then i'll post it.. Thanks buddy :)

Comment: Hi, any idea regarding this ?