# javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException Mandatory child node jcr:content not found in a new node

Tags: aem

When using JcrUtil.createPath to create a folder (directory) in DAM Asset in AEM, an exception is thrown with error **OakConstraint0025: /content/dam/upload/Type/99/MBT/front[[nt:file]]: Mandatory child node jcr:content not found in a new node**. It may mean that the child jcr:content node needs to be created in the same time with the directory. So I really do not know how to resolve this problem.

```
    // get resource resolver
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getResourceResolver(Collections.<String, Object>singletonMap(JcrResourceConstants.AUTHENTICATION_INFO_SESSION, session));

    AssetManager assetMgr = resourceResolver.adaptTo(AssetManager.class);

    // creating directory in DAM Asset
    Node newParentNode = JcrUtil.createPath(splitParentPath, true, "sling:OrderedFolder", "nt:file", session, true);
    newParentNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");

    // moving DAM Asset
    assetMgr.moveAsset(fileNode.getPath(), splitParentPath + "/" + newFileName);
```

I did follow this JCRUtil API https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/javadoc/com/day/cq/commons/jcr/JcrUtil.html#createPath(Node,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20Session,%20boolean), and this [How to create a directory on the basis of path in cq5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30570738/how-to-create-a-directory-on-the-basis-of-path-in-cq5)

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the auto save flag to the createPath method is turned on. This will try to commit the nodes to repo even before you have been able to add the jcr:content child node node.

Try to save after the child node has been added

```
// creating directory in DAM Asset
Node newParentNode = JcrUtil.createPath(splitParentPath, true, "sling:OrderedFolder", "nt:file", session, false);
newParentNode.addNode("jcr:content", "nt:resource");
session.save()
```

Comment: It does work, but only when I remove "resourceResolver.commit()" because it caused the error. I use "session.save()" instead.